# Angular 5 - Data not displaying in template

Tags: angular, angular5, observable

I am using angular 5 and I am struggling to get data to display on my template from a rest endpoint using observables.

My component is as follows

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from './news.service';
import { NewsItem } from './newsItem.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  //templateUrl: './news.component.html',
template: `
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let newsItem of newsItems">{{newsItem}}</li>
  </ul>
  <h3 *ngIf="newsItems"> {{ newsItems }} </h3> 

  <h3 *ngIf="test"> test: {{ test | async}} </h3>`,
  styleUrls: ['./news.component.css']
})
export class NewsComponent implements OnInit {

  newsItems: NewsItem[];
  test : string;

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService) { 
    this.newsItems = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.newsService.getLatestNews().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('1 Component Data:', data);
        data.forEach(function (newsItem) {
          console.log('2 Component Data:', newsItem);
        });

        this.newsItems = data;
        this.test = 'Hello';
        console.log('3 Component newsItems:', this.newsItems);
        console.log('4 Component test:', this.test);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

My service is as follows

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs';
import { NewsItem } from './newsItem.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class NewsService {

  newsEndpoint:string = 'http://myendpoint.com/services/news';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getLatestNews(): Observable<NewsItem[]>{
       return this.httpClient.get<NewsItem[]>(this.newsEndpoint, {
          observe: 'body',
          responseType: 'json'
        });
  }

}
```

The data is printing to the console in the ngOnInit method but nothing will output in the template

I am trying to create an angular application for the sharepoint framework using this template - https://github.com/maliksahil/SPFxAngularCLI

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Should work @ first glance. Can you create Stackblitz?? (just mock returned data in service)

Comment: Maybe some sort of exception is thrown on runtime ?

Comment: Also        `observe: 'body',
          responseType: 'json'` can be ommited since Angular5 (or 4)

Comment: no "template" property inside @Component decorator?

Comment: Have removed observe: 'body', responseType: 'json' and its the same.

Comment: No exceptions are being thrown at runtime

Comment: does this console.log('3 Component newsItems:', this.newsItems); printing all value?

Comment: yes it prints all values

Comment: Using the cdr:ChangeDetectorRef worked. I am developing the app for the sharepoint framework - could this lead to issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ChangeDetectorRef

```
 constructor(private newsService: NewsService,private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) { 
    this.newsItems = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.newsService.getLatestNews().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('1 Component Data:', data);
        data.forEach(function (newsItem) {
          console.log('2 Component Data:', newsItem);
        });

        this.newsItems = data;
        this.cdr.detectChanges()
        this.test = 'Hello';
        console.log('3 Component newsItems:', this.newsItems);
        console.log('4 Component test:', this.test);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: This worked - I am creating an app for the sharepoint framework using the template https://github.com/maliksahil/SPFxAngularCLI. Should this ChangeDetectorRef class be used or is it an ok practice??

Comment: yes it is okay to detect changes manually sometimes check angular doc:https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef